# facebook - "like this" url problem in asp page

Tags: asp.net, facebook

I put the facebook "like this" widget on my pages and i have a problem:

My url is dynamically constructed with this method:

```
protected String getCurrentUrl()
{
    return Server.HtmlEncode(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
}
```

so the facebook iframe is:

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=<%= getCurrentUrl() %>&amp;layout=standard&amp;show_faces=true&amp;width=450&amp;action=like&amp;font=verdana&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=80"
scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border: none; overflow: hidden; width: 450px;
height: 80px;" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Well, an example of the getCurrentUrl result is:

> http://gramma.ro/Site/DetaliiProdus.aspx?c=m1&p=427&s1=41&s2=72

But, because of those "&" (& - when encoded) facebook does not correctly grab the link:

- it takes:

> http://gramma.ro/Site/DetaliiProdus.aspx?c=m1

instead of the whole one of the above...so it stops at the first &.

Do you see any workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to Url encode:

```
return Server.UrlEncode(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
```

Although I would suggest you generating this url with something among the lines:

```
public string GetFaceBookAddress()
{
    var builder = new UriBuilder("http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php");
    var nvc = new NameValueCollection
    {
        { "href", Request.Url.AbsoluteUri },
        { "layout", "standard" },
        { "show_faces", "true" },
        { "width", "450" },
        { "action", "like" },
        { "font", "verdana" },
        { "colorscheme", "light" },
        { "font", "80" },
    };
    builder.Query = ToQueryString(nvc);
    return builder.ToString();
}

private static string ToQueryString(NameValueCollection nvc)
{
    return string.Join("&", Array.ConvertAll(nvc.AllKeys, key => string.Format("{0}={1}", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(key), HttpUtility.UrlEncode(nvc[key]))));
}
```

And then:

```
<iframe src="<%= Server.HtmlEncode(GetFaceBookAddress()) %>" ...
```

Comment: @Christian, please see my update about a suggestion of using an improved function.